Promoting StackExchange via blog posts
I wrote a blog post trying to convince scientists to use StackExchange more. I could use some feedback and suggestions before I start trying to publicize it.
Is it convincing? What arguments need work? Should I add pictures somehow?

Targeting a scientific audience, I would not use contractions: e.g., "it's" Will read it more thoroughly this evening.

Don't publicize it until we are ready for the push to have decent content

@honi are we tracking the progress towards that goal somewhere?

https://cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/cognitive-sciences-reboot-2017-call-for-action
